# Should I Shift from Laravel 4 to Laravel 5 for My New Project

Tags: laravel

I've use L4 in my old project, for about 1.5 years. Now I'm facing new project, should I shift to L5 ? How long it will be to learn L5, are there any major change happen from L4 to L5 that make it difficult to shift ?

Comment: Funny you mentioned "shift". I recently released a service - named Laravel *Shift* - that will [upgrade your Laravel projects automatically](https://laravelshift.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now or in the future you are likely to migrate from Laravel 4 to Laravel 5. Why not give it a shot right now? [Laravel has good migration documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations). Areas where care needs to be taken are marked in red notes.

Laravel also has [upgrade path documentation from 4.2](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/upgrade#upgrade-5.0). I would highly recommend setting up a virtual machine (VM) with your environment, taking a snapshot of the VM,  and performing the upgrade in the VM until you get comfortable. Note down steps on a piece of paper. Revert the snapshot to bring the VM back to the state it was before the upgrade and follow the steps you had written down. Once successful, perform the migration on the main system (and take backups before you begin).

Check out Laravel 5's release notes here to get a better understanding of the changes: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/releases#laravel-5.0.

The level of difficulty is medium (not too hard, not too easy), I feel.